# what is "translate" and why does it want access to my keychain?

Tags: email, keychain, malware

I use Entourage for my email accounts but I keep getting a pop up saying 
"translate wants to use your confidential information stored in "[my email account]" in your keychain.
 Do you want to allow access to this item?"

By always allowing I found the location through keychain - /usr/libexec/oah/translate but I can't locate it through finder.

I am worried that this might be malware, does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Are you using Entourage 2004?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `/usr/libexec/oah/translate` is [Rosetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_%28software%29), an Apple program to allow programs developed for PowerPC architecture to run on the newest Intel Mac.

So I don't think it's a malware, just Mac OS using Rosetta to run Entourage.

Answer (score 0):

/usr is a hidden folder, so that's why you normally can't see it. I use iTweaX to show these, but I'm sure there are other methods.

I just today got this same thing in Entourage, so I scanned the libexec subfolder with ClamXav, just to be careful. It showed no viruses. After I did a hard restart of the Mac, all seems to be back to normal in Entourage. Unfortunately, I still have no idea what suddenly caused these keychain requests to appear, after years of using Entourage.

I also just ran across this in Apple Support Communities: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2123451?tstart=0

FWIW, I'm running MacOS 10.6.8, and Entourage 2004 11.4.0, on a 2007 MacBook.